# Help with udev rules my Keyboard thinks it's a Joystick

Tags: arch-linux, keyboard, udev, joystick

I'm running Archlinux and I have a weird problem my "Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600" gets picked up as a Joystick and a Keyboard for some reason.

```
Note: Output trimmed
─$ xinput list
  Virtual core pointer                id=2[master pointer  (3)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600    id=9[slave  pointer  (2)]
  Virtual core keyboard               id=3[master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Microsoft Wired Keyboard 600    id=8[slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The problem is I have an Xbox360 Controller that I use to play games with and this other **"Joystick"** is messing things up.

I have a workaround but it's manual and annoying i use this.

```
sudo chmod 0000 /dev/input/event1 /dev/input/js0
sudo setfacl -b /dev/input/event1 /dev/input/js0
```

Now I know I can set udev rules to do things to devices when plugged in and out ect... and I have tried to get it working but I'm just at a loss.

I'd like to have the Joystick part of this keyboard not even show up in `/dev/input` but still have the keyboard bit work.

The following is some `udevadm` output for this keyboard if someone could help me out I'd appreciate it very much.

The actual keyboard

```
─$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/input/event0                                                                            1 ↵
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:045E:0750.0007/input/input23/event0
N: input/event0
S: input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600-event-kbd
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.0-event-kbd /dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600-event-kbd
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:045E:0750.0007/input/input23/event0
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_MODEL=Wired_Keyboard_600
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Wired\x20Keyboard\x20600
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0750
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_1_0
E: ID_REVISION=0110
E: ID_SERIAL=Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
E: ID_VENDOR=Microsoft
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Microsoft
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=045e
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/45e/750/111:usb-0000:00:1a.0-1
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=64
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4429367119
```

The funny ghost Joystick

```
─$ udevadm info --query=all --name=/dev/input/event1
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:045E:0750.0008/input/input24/event1
N: input/event1
S: input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600-if01-event-joystick
S: input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event-joystick
E: DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-id/usb-Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600-if01-event-joystick /dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.1-event-joystick
E: DEVNAME=/dev/input/event1
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:045E:0750.0008/input/input24/event1
E: ID_BUS=usb
E: ID_FOR_SEAT=input-pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_1_1
E: ID_INPUT=1
E: ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEY=1
E: ID_INPUT_KEYBOARD=1
E: ID_MODEL=Wired_Keyboard_600
E: ID_MODEL_ENC=Wired\x20Keyboard\x20600
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0750
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1:1.1
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_1a_0-usb-0_1_1_1
E: ID_REVISION=0110
E: ID_SERIAL=Microsoft_Wired_Keyboard_600
E: ID_TYPE=hid
E: ID_USB_DRIVER=usbhid
E: ID_USB_INTERFACES=:030101:030000:
E: ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=01
E: ID_VENDOR=Microsoft
E: ID_VENDOR_ENC=Microsoft
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=045e
E: LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=3/45e/750/111:usb-0000:00:1a.0-1
E: MAJOR=13
E: MINOR=65
E: SUBSYSTEM=input
E: TAGS=:seat:uaccess:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=4429367514
```

Comment: Do you have `xpad` installed or anything like it? Can you verify that other keyboards don't also turn up as joysticks?

Comment: Ok I have xpad installed.
I'll go check the keyboard thing but my only other keyboard is a wireless and works via a Logitech dongle

Comment: Yeah, so it's probably xpad. It does a thing where it emulates keyboard input with a joystick and vice-versa - you can use the keyboard/gamepad to move the mouse pointer and other such stuff. I'm pretty sure your wireless logitech will do the same. Do `man xpad` and try to figure out how to make it work for you, or else `pacman -Rns xpad`.

Comment: My Logitech dongle only adds one keyboard and one mouse as expected

Comment: When you say xpad you mean the kernel module right?

Comment: hmmm... maybe that's because it has a mouse? or maybe I'm just wrong, but it can't hurt to read the docs, man.

Comment: no. I don't even mean xpad at all - I guess I meant *xboxdrv*. Good catch.

Comment: I don't have xboxdrv installed i find it hard to use and all it really adds is no blinking light on the controller

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26509/discussion-between-demented-and-mikeserv).